# Issue with Python Module Import

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am encountering a weird import issue with Python module hoping to get some insight on.
I have the below following Folder Structure.

Folder Structure:

```
SomeProject
* Test/
    * __init__.py
    * TestModuleA.py
    * TestModuleB.py
    * TestModuleC.py
* __init__.py
* ModuleA.py
* ModuleB.py
* ModuleC.py
```

I was trying to run some of the test case with

```sh
python SomeProject/Test/TestModuleA.py
python SomeProject/Test/TestModuleB.py
python SomeProject/Test/TestModuleC.py
```

For some reason `python SomeProject/Test/TestModuleA.py` works fine, but `python SomeProject/Test/TestModuleB.py` came back with and error of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SomeProject.ModuleB'`.

I looked through the code, how `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` set up is pretty much the same, and how they are imported into `TestModuleA` and `TestModuleB` is same as well.

Also if I add `from SomeProject.ModuleA import ModuleA` from `ModuleB` it works fine.

I also tried running `python -m unittest SomeProject/Test/TestModuleB.py` and that seemed to work fine.

So I am wondering what's the discrepancy that could cause `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` to be different?

`Test/__init__.py`

```py
name = 'Test'
```

`Test/TestModuleA.py`

```py
from SomeProject.ModuleA import ModuleA
...

class TestModuleA(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

def suite():
    """Test Suite."""
    # Create the Unit Test Suite
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    # Load a suite of all test cases contained in `testCaseClass`
    test_module_a = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestModuleA)
    # Add the test suite
    suite.addTest(test_module_a)
    # Return the Test Suite
    return suite

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite())
```

`Test/TestModuleB.py`

```py
from SomeProject.ModuleB import ModuleB
...

class TestModuleB(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

def suite():
    ...
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite())
```

`Test/TestModuleC.py`

```py
from SomeProject.ModuleC import ModuleC
...

class TestModuleC(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

def suite():
    ...
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite())
```

`__init__.py`

```py
# Blank
```

`ModuleA.py`

```py
class ModuleA:
    __init__(self):
        ...
...
```

`ModuleB.py`

```py
class ModuleB:
    __init__(self):
        ...
...
```

`ModuleC.py`

```py
class ModuleC:
    __init__(self):
        ...
...
```

Comment: Clearly something is wrong with your code, can you provide the real sample code?

Comment: full source is in GitHub: https://github.com/YTKme/Python-SFDCFW/tree/development

mainly the `TestSFDCFW.py` class cannot call `Metadata.py` on the same level as `SFDCFW.py`, but it can import `Access.py` and `Rest.py` fine